# QML Text Drop Shadow

Tags: qt, qml, dropshadow

Is there a proper way of adding outer shadow to a text object in QML? I've tried to use the DropShadow but it fills the whole text field with black.

```
Text {
    id: textId
    font.pixelSize: 36
    font.letterSpacing: 0.9
    color: "red"
    text: "Hello World"

    DropShadow {
        anchors.fill: parent
        verticalOffset: 2
        color: "#80000000"
        radius: 1
        samples: 3
    }
}
```

I've also tried to replace anchors.fill with source and set the text id. Also with DropShadow outside of the Text object. No shadow is present.

My goal is to get the equivalent of the css style

```
text-shadow: 0 2px 4px
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [item layers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#item-layers):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Text {
        id: textId
        font.pixelSize: 36
        font.letterSpacing: 0.9
        color: "red"
        text: "Hello World"

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: DropShadow {
            verticalOffset: 2
            color: "#80000000"
            radius: 1
            samples: 3
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do it like it's done in the `DropShadow` [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-dropshadow.html), where the `DropShadow` is a sibling item:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Text {
        id: textId
        font.pixelSize: 36
        font.letterSpacing: 0.9
        color: "red"
        text: "Hello World"
    }

    DropShadow {
        anchors.fill: textId
        source: textId
        verticalOffset: 2
        color: "#80000000"
        radius: 1
        samples: 3
    }
}
```

You're missing the `source` assignment in your case, but you'll also get errors about recursive rendering if you try to have the shadow as a child of the `Text`:

> ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the layers and the effect is applied, but if I apply anchors to the Text Object it ignores it. But if I use the second method and have the DropShadow as a sibling it will use the anchors.

Comment: Ah, it seems like if you take `anchors.fill: parent` out of the first snippet then it still works. I may have accidentally left it in. Updated the answer.